# String format for Japanese currency

Tags: asp.net

I want to display Japanese currency format on Label text which is in GridView.I want to do it in aspx page.
How can I do this? It should display like ￥100,000. I have tried this one but did not get output.Please suggest me correction.

```
<asp:Label ID="LblPrice" runat="server" Width="100px" Text='<%# string.Format (  "{0:C,ja-JP}",Eval("Amount")) %>'  /
```

Comment: Try with `string.Format(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), "{0:C}", Eval("Amount"))`. Note that you should probably save the `new CultureInfo("ja-JP")` in a field somewhere in the page. And it will display `¥100,000` without space between the currency symbol and the number

Comment: @xanatos how should I save the new CultureInfo("ja-JP") in aspx page.please help me I am new to asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), "{0:C}", Eval("Amount")).
```

Note that you should probably save the `new CultureInfo("ja-JP")` in a field somewhere in the page.

In the C# code of the page add a field like:

```
protected CultureInfo japaneseCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
```

then write

```
string.Format(japaneseCulture, "{0:C}", Eval("Amount"))
```

Note that `ja-jp` will display ¥100,000 without space between the currency symbol and the number.

Comment: still not getting the o/p.